# Big accuracy difference between cross-validation and testing with a test set in weka? is it normal?

Tags: weka, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm new with weka and I have a problem with my classification project using it.

I have a train dataset with 1000 instances and one of 200 for testing. The problem is that when I try to test the performance of some algorithms (like randomforest), the number given by cross-validation and test set is really different.

Here is an example with cross-validation

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -I 100 -K 0 -S 1
Relation:     testData-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W10000000-prune-rate-1.0-T-I-N0-L-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.IteratedLovinsStemmer-M1-O-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters " \r\n\t.,;:\"\'()?!--+-í+*&#$\\/=<>[]_`@"-weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection-Eweka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval-Sweka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T 0.0 -N -1
Instances:    1000
Attributes:   276
[list of attributes omitted]
Test mode:10-fold cross-validation

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Random forest of 100 trees, each constructed while considering 9 random features.
Out of bag error: 0.269



Time taken to build model: 4.9 seconds

=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         740               74      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       260               26      %
Kappa statistic                          0.5674
Mean absolute error                      0.2554
Root mean squared error                  0.3552
Relative absolute error                 60.623  %
Root relative squared error             77.4053 %
Total Number of Instances             1000     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.479     0.083      0.723     0.479     0.576      0.795    I
                 0.941     0.352      0.707     0.941     0.808      0.894    E
                 0.673     0.023      0.889     0.673     0.766      0.964    R
Weighted Avg.    0.74      0.198      0.751     0.74      0.727      0.878

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 149 148  14 |   a = I
  24 447   4 |   b = E
  33  37 144 |   c = R
```

72.5% , it's something...

But now if I try with a my test set of 200 instances...

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -I 100 -K 0 -S 1
Relation:     testData-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W10000000-prune-rate-1.0-T-I-N0-L-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.IteratedLovinsStemmer-M1-O-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters " \r\n\t.,;:\"\'()?!--+-í+*&#$\\/=<>[]_`@"-weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection-Eweka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval-Sweka.attributeSelection.Ranker -T 0.0 -N -1
Instances:    1000
Attributes:   276
[list of attributes omitted]
Test mode:user supplied test set: size unknown (reading incrementally)

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Random forest of 100 trees, each constructed while considering 9 random features.
Out of bag error: 0.269



Time taken to build model: 4.72 seconds

=== Evaluation on test set ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances          86               43      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       114               57      %
Kappa statistic                          0.2061
Mean absolute error                      0.3829
Root mean squared error                  0.4868
Relative absolute error                 84.8628 %
Root relative squared error             99.2642 %
Total Number of Instances              200     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.17      0.071      0.652     0.17      0.27       0.596    I
                 0.941     0.711      0.312     0.941     0.468      0.796    E
                 0.377     0          1         0.377     0.548      0.958    R
Weighted Avg.    0.43      0.213      0.671     0.43      0.405      0.758

=== Confusion Matrix ===

  a  b  c   <-- classified as
 15 73  0 |  a = I
  3 48  0 |  b = E
  5 33 23 |  c = R
```

43% ... obviously, something is really wrong, I used batch filtering with test set

What am I doing wrong? I manually classified the test and train set using the same criteria, so I find strange that differences.

I think I got the concept behind CV, but maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is your training error?

Comment: sorry but...how can I know the training error with weka(gui)?

Comment: Select *use training set* option

Comment: Correctly Classified Instances         988               98.8    %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        12                1.2    %

As some people already told me, it's seems I have a big problem of overfitting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from your comment, this is the statistics:

*CV error:* 26%

*Test error:* 57%

*Training error:* 1.2%

A low training error is always fishy. The first thing to do if you get low error is to check CV error or Test error. If there is a big difference between the training and test/CV error, then there is a possibility of overfitting. This is a very good *sanity test*. And of course then you have other methods like learning curves to confirm whether your model overfits or not. *Overfitting* means that your model cannot *generalize* well--it only knows the training data or it only is a fit for *the* training data, in *general* if you apply this model to unknown data, it will not be able to fit itself.

So, coming back to your problem--CV and Test can be seen as two independent cases of testing *generalization* capacity of your model. If you have a model that overfits, it will not be able to generalize well. So, in the case of CV it gives one result while for the test, it gives you a different one.

Hope that helps?